# detecting sleeping eyes with openCV

Tags: c#, opencv

i'm using openCVSharp, it is a OpenCV binding for C#, i want to detect the eye state (opened/closed)

my current process works fine in a certain lightness and doesn't work other wise, i depend on detecting the eye line when sleeping as the eye form 1 horizontal line when closed and many lines when opened.

the process is

1. detect face with haar cascade
2. detect left and right eyes separately with haar cascade (works more precise if detected separately)
3. apply in range filter with min=0 and max=Average_intensity_of_eye_region-offset
4. smooth the eye region
5. use HoughLines to detect number of lines
6. make statistics with lines numbers
7. if there is 1 lines most of the recent frames then eye is closed

note that i'm working with dell laptop webcam which has low resolution.
any better algorithm to apply? as i mentioned that works is certain lightness and doesn't in other lightness.

Note: i noticed that in higher lightness the in range filter produce a white spot instead on horizontal line, so i think the solution would be adjusting inrange filter with lightness but i can't figure out how.

Comment: I'm intrigued. Why\when would you want to detect if someone is sleeping?

Comment: If you fall asleep at your laptop, then it can sound an alarm thus waking you...

Comment: The Hough transform is a notoriously finicky way to collect information on the presence of lines in an image.  You might have better luck looking for the presence/area of the sclera (white of the eye) using a blob find.

Comment: @chibacity it'll be applied to the car in case to alert sleeping driver

Comment: @Blaze That's very interesting, good luck.

Comment: Perhaps you should alert everone else around the vehicle - so they can get out of the way.

Comment: @DanBryant can't find any article about blob find? any help with that ?

Comment: OpenCV blob finding: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib

Comment: How about haar cascades? Train your classifier to detect whether eyes are drowsy or not.

Comment: This could be a good starting point: http://youtu.be/i8Y9H3ve8fA